# Crear un queryset en Django con relaciones Many To Many

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Necesito capturar todos los recursos asociados a una sesión, pero los recursos perteneces a diferentes actividades, mi modelos se ven asi.

```
class Recurso(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Actividad(models.Model):
    name_a = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=0)
    preparation = models.CharField(max_length=600)

    objetives = models.ManyToManyField(Objetivo, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria, blank=True)
    resource = models.ManyToManyField(Recurso, blank=True)
    plan_duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    real_duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    energy_cost = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    a_retros_coments = models.CharField(max_length=500) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_a

class Sesion(models.Model):
    actividad = models.ManyToManyField(Actividad, blank=True)
    start_date_time = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    scpec_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    end_date_time = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    preparation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    s_retros_coments = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.scpec_location
```

y el Viewset que intento crear así:

```
class RecursosSession(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sesion.objects.filter(actividad__resource).all()
    serializer_class = RecursoSerial
```

Desde la consola solo tengo la respuesta de error que me indica que mis modelos no estan definidos en la funcion filter.

```
queryset = Sesion.objects.filter(actividad__resource).all()
NameError: name 'actividad__resource' is not define
```

Agradecería mucho de su ayuda, estoy entrando en crisis.

Comment: Estas filtrando todas las sesiones, no tiene sentido, debería ser para una sesión especifica no?

Comment: Necesito solo los recursos de una sesión, si puedo traer de vuelta un arreglo así para todas las sesiones seria ideal.

Comment: Ya publique mi respuesta échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recuperar todos los recursos de todas las sesiones, seria así:

```
sesiones = dict()

for sesion in Sesion.objects.all():
    for actividad in sesion.actividad_set.all():
        # Aqui exactamente obtienes los recursos: actividad.recurso_set.all()
        sesiones[sesion] = actividad.recurso_set.all()
```

Guardo los datos en un diccionario para tener mas organizado los datos.
Puedes guardar los datos como tu quieras, según tu necesidad. Y adaptarlo a tu ViewSet.

La estructura del diccionario seria algo así:

```
{
    'sesion_1': <QuerySet[...]>, # Recursos de la sesión "sesion_1"
    'sesion_2': <QuerySet[...]>, # Recursos de ...
    ...
}
```

Para obtener los recursos de una sesión en especifico seria así:

```
sesion = Sesion.objects.get(...)

recursos = [actividad.recurso_set.all() for actividad in sesion.actividad_set.all()]
```

Espero haberte ayudado.